# Find out which application you are currently on using terminal Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal

Is there a way to know what application you are currently viewing through the terminal?

e.g., if I am on Chrome the bar shows that I am on Chrome
on the top left of Ubuntu.

[image]

If I am currently on Files,
it would show that I am on files on the top left corner.

[image]

Would there be a way to view this information on the terminal?

Comment: Most terminal programs put it in the title bar,but sometimes that's terminal program specific. Since you don't say which you are using I recommend using tmux which will let you put it in the status / title bar regardless of a specific terminal program.